Using Array Field for Filtering Rows
I have a field which contains an array of Tags. I would like to be able to filter my table based on whether each row contains that tag. However Looker seems to be treating the entire array as an entity rather than allowing me to filter individually by each tag.
For example: I want to be able to filter to show all rows that contain "Blog" for example, not which equal  "Article, Blog, Image".

Sebastian’s answer worked. However (for future readers) I found a better and much easier solution. There is a free community plugin called CSV Filter which is a control that filters array fields: https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/2b0a22a2-3992-49e1-be12-bdc22937daea/page/WoxLB

Good stuff! Much easier indeed!

This is doable, but not as straightforward as you would expect. This unnecessarily complicated approach is required because in Looker Studio a filter cannot use a parameter value directly. So:
I have created a test table looking like this:



id
type
spent




1
["Article", "Blog", "Image"]
12.34


2
["Image" "Blog"]
24.43



First, and this is the major downside, you need to manually create a parameter for your data source ("Add a parameter"). Let's call it "param_types". It contains all the different values for project type, like this:

Then you create a Drop-Down List and set the control field to your newly created parameter "param_types".
Then you create a Custom Variable (let's call it "type_contains_param") that returns True/False if the selected dropdown item (param_types) is contained in the type array, like this:
CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(type, param_types) THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END

This custom variable you can use as a filter for your table. Create a new filter  defined as
Include / type_contains_param / True

and apply it to your table.
Make sure that your table's "Paramters" (SET-UP pane) is set to "Default (<>)", otherwise this won't work. When you select Default it should display as "param_types".

Voilà.

@brian-barrus, any joy here?

Great answer Sebastian. It seems to work even if it's more painful than it seems it should be. Thanks you!

My problem is: The Parameter dropdown control only allows me to select one parameter at a time and I would like to be able to filter to select multiple. (Blog ✔️ Article ✔️ Signage ✔️ )
